# Positioning a control Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, position, dynamically-generated

I know how to do it in win forms, but how do i position a dynamically added control on top of another dynamically added control code behind?

I tried doing: `panelNew.ApplyStyle(panelOld.ControlStyle);`

where panelNew and panelOld are Panels and I am trying to position panelNew on top of panelOld but it did not do anything.  (Both panels are exactly same size)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it purely in code-behind, try something like this:

```
panelNew.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position] = 'absolute';
panelNew.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.ZIndex] = '999';
```

The zindex of the panel you want on the top will have to be greater than the other panel.

Comment: This gave me an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would likely want to leverage `absolute` positioning. Think about it like this, it's all about the styling. Consider the following style:

```
#pnl1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#pnl2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

`#pnl2` is now directly above `#pnl1`.